# My laptop is stuck on boot

Tags: boot, 22.04, acpi

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with the KDE Plasma DE (I can't remember what version I'm on, but it should be 5.something). I seem to have updated Linux itself to the latest version from Discover then rebooted my laptop when prompted to and it hasn't proceeded past this for a full day now. Here's the message currently on my screen.

```
[ 0.340852] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [^CPUO._PPC), AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[ 0.340891] ACPI Error: Aborting method_PR.PPCE due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[ 0.340899] ACPI Error: Aborting method \EV12 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[ 0.340906] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SMIE due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[ 0.340914] ACPI Error: Aborting method \NEVT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[ 0.340920] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[ 1.585003] ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 37
[ 1.585466] ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 38
[ 3.152958] hid-generic 0003:1532:0099.0005: No inputs registered, leaving
```

Is there a keybord combination I need to press to fix this or am I going to have to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. I really don't want to have to go back to Windows as I've been enjoying Ubuntu so far.

Ubuntu boots just fine when I go through "Recovery mode" and "Resume".

Comment: What is the GPU? What do you man by "the latest version of Linux"?

Comment: Nvidia K2000M, and by the latest version of Linux, I mean just that. The file size was over 100mb, and I believe it was called linux kernel or something like that

Comment: It would help me if you're specific with details; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with KDE, so this was a Ubuntu Desktop install on which you added `kubuntu-desktop` or something else?  or you installed Kubuntu 22.04 LTS?  Did you upgrade the KDE using backports? if so which one... If you're specific with details, we can better understand what *software stack* you're using & thus what are likely the best recovery options... Ubuntu *jammy* with HWE recently switched from 5.15 kernel to 5.19 so I wonder if that's at play; if it is selecting an older 5.15 kernel at grub should still boot..

Comment: As there are different default to an install if you used Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or Kubuntu 22.04 LTS media; being specific lets us better understand (*with differences with 22.04(.1) & 22.04.2 media for Kubuntu too*) so we're somewhat limited in what we can suggest given lack of details as to your stack.  If you're using Kubuntu I have no objection with you calling it Ubuntu (*I do myself! as it is to me*) but its helpful if you're specific. [Official flavors like Kubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 22.04 then installed the KDE Plasma Desktop Environment. If there's any more info I can give about my install, ask away.

Comment: What packages you installed with adding the KDE Plasma desktop are useful... I'm a *lover* of multiple DE installs on my systems, and would normally add `kubuntu-desktop` to get everything, but if you install it using other small *meta* or other packages; the results differ based on release, so please be specific with details.  If your install was Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop media then you're using the HWE kernel (*as per my prior comment on that*) so try older 5.15 at grub as suggested.

Comment: I picked the option that installs everything KDE. How do I change the grub version? Entering "Advanced Options For Ubuntu" reveals 4 options
5.19, 5.19 recovery, 5.15 and 5.15 recovery. 5.15 works as normal so how do I get Ubuntu to start with that by default rather than 5.19?

Comment: installs everything?   To me that implies `kubuntu-desktop` as that contains all of KDE & everything Kubuntu prepared for use in Ubuntu. If you use something else you should specially say. 5.15 is the GA kernel stack for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS & the default if installed with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, Kubuntu 22.04/22.04.1 media.. but not Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS media which defaults to HWE (as does Kubuntu 22.04.2) . Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details on GA/HWE kernel stack; both stacks can co-exist except if some nvidia etc. kernel modules are used

Comment: In that case, yeah I used `kubuntu-desktop`. The link doesn't give me info on how to boot with 5.15 instead of the latest one